# how to open component view then remove button tag from html code

Tags: angular

brief: outside it has magnify glass then click the glass it open component but after that it still shows the glass. How can I remove or disable html button( contain i tag after open about() func )

.ts file

```
about(index) {
    this.dialogSv.open(ProductDetailComponent, {
      data: { actions: this.actions }
    });
  }
```

.html file

```
 <button (click)="about(i)">
     <i class="ec-search"></i>
 </button>
```

Comment: you need to toggle the functionality, share stackblitz, since there is very less info we can cultivate out from your question

Comment: it just images which have zoom in for detail (I use carousel for this case), after zoom in I want to disable or hidden that (zoom in) button

Comment: what is the use of index parameter? you are not even using it.. your question seems to be vague, can you share StackBlitz so we can look at the exact requirement/issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boolean variable to maintain the state of button as:

**.ts file**

```
isButtonDiabled = false;

about(index) {
    this.isButtonDiabled = true;
    const dialogRef = this.dialogSv.open(ProductDetailComponent, {
      data: { actions: this.actions }
    });

    // add listener for close of dialog and set this.isButtonDiabled = false; there
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        this.isButtonDiabled = false;
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <button (click)="about(i)" [disabled]="isButtonDiabled">
     <i class="ec-search"></i>
 </button>
```